# Get a second wind

Tags: vocabulary, american-english

I am trying to learn about the phrase  “get a second wind”.
I have made below two sentences. Is this correct?

> 1)Once you take a short nap in the afternoon you will surely get a second wind to continue with your work
>
> 2) Project failed last time . I hope you have got second wind if you are considering to start over it again

Comment: What is your question? Note that asking "Is this correct" needs to be backed by some reasoning about why you think it is or is not correct. and why you think there is some doubt.

Comment: Your first example seems like a natural enough context for this idiomatic usage. But I don't think the second one works (I can't see any direct connection between having previously worked on a failed project, and being "exhausted" in such a way as to benefit from "renewed energy"). But it's hard for me to explain exactly what "contextual constraints" I *think* are being violated, and not every other native speaker would feel the same as me anyway. My advice would be to avoid actually ***using*** the idiomatic form at all, to avoid making "mistakes".

Comment: (There are many other elements in *both* your examples that make it pretty obvious to a native speaker that you're *not*. I think you should focus on the basics for now, and leave "advanced idiomatic metaphoric language" for another day.)

Comment: These would be idiomatic: 1) *After a short afternoon nap you'll get your second wind. Then you can carry on with your work.* 2) (Project failed last time is not a sentence.) *I hope you've got your second wind if you're thinking of starting again.* In the UK I think we usually say "my/your/his/her/its/our/your/their second wind": not "**a** second wind".

Comment: I guess it is nicer to show the effort you already made, such as the definition/explanation and examples on dictionary or other trusted reference.